# Encode URLRequest httpBody parameters

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm trying to build enum Router to make requests a little easier, like this:

```swift
loginRequest(Router.singIn(["login" : "test", "password": "123123"]), completion: {response in
  print(response)
})
```

Router.swift:

```swift
enum Router: URLRequestConvertible {

  case singIn([String : String])

  ...

  private var params: Parameters? {
    switch self {
    case .singIn(let args):
      return args
    }
  }

  func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest {
    let API_BASE = try "http://localhost:3000/api/v1".asURL()
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: API_BASE.appendingPathComponent(path))
    urlRequest.httpMethod = method.rawValue
    if let parameters = params {
      do {
        urlRequest.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])
      }
    }
    return urlRequest
  }
}
```

But my API gets this parameters:

```
{"{\"password\":\"123123\",\"login\":\"test\"}"=>"123123"}
```

What did i do wrong?

Comment: Got it - never pointed Content-Type Header
```swift
urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```